# How to do right responsive view for blocks

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

Will start from the beginning, I need to make this page: 
http://prntscr.com/m4ddwi

It seems kind of easy, but I receive some problems with it. 
I thought to use grid, but moved forward with `Flexbox`.

Well, main problem, when I resize the window - input and `textareas` changes, and width start to be different, and idk why to be honest.

Now it looks ok, http://prntscr.com/m4df1k 
but when I start to resize the window, some mess begin: http://prntscr.com/m4df9u

CSS for input and `textarea` the same - http://prntscr.com/m4dfhb

Here my html for this: http://prntscr.com/m4dg7j
and my `scss` as well: http://prntscr.com/m4dfwh

The problem with blocks, their resizing, and not remain the same, I only added flex-grow: 1, not shrink, so everything changes because of content, but why? How I can to prevent it?

I uploaded everything to github.io, link:

```
https://github.com/hordynsky/hordynsky.github.io/tree/master/moderne - code

https://hordynsky.github.io/moderne/pages/order.html - page
```

Will be glad to receive any help here. 
Hope without negative feedbacks, all of you were there, were trying to learn things...

UPD: 
About the code, better for you to see it on github, I think. 
The main files is: 
https://github.com/hordynsky/hordynsky.github.io/blob/master/moderne/sass/pages/_order.scss - (the scss for this page)
https://github.com/hordynsky/hordynsky.github.io/blob/master/moderne/sass/components/_form.scss - (the scss for the form and input/textarea itself)
https://github.com/hordynsky/hordynsky.github.io/blob/master/moderne/pages/order.html - ( my order page )

UPD1: The main problem in this example: http://prntscr.com/m4dmet - I added the same block, with the same text, width of the block with form now 588px. 
But, I need to add another text, added and the form width now... 721px - http://prntscr.com/m4dmz7

I just want it always to be the same. 
That my form block and text block always be the same 1:1 ratio.

Comment: And sorry about pictures view, I don't have enough "reputation" on the site to make it right.

Comment: Please add a code snippet or jsfiddle link. thanks

Comment: Please add the code as text not as image. Noones going to type your code from an image. You should add a [mcve]. And noones going to clone your repo as well.

Comment: I added links to github for specific files, is it ok, guys?

Comment: i feel like its not the resizing blocks, but there is something pushing it away, making it smaller then wanted

Comment: The main problem in this example: http://prntscr.com/m4dmet - I added the same block, with the same text, width of the block with form now 588px. 
But, I need to add another text, added and the form width now... 721px - http://prntscr.com/m4dmz7  

I just want it always to be the same. 
That my form block and text block always be the same 1:1 ratio.

Comment: @RamondeVries, yes, you're right! I can't find a solution for this :(

Comment: Someone can help? :)

Comment: in your `_order.scss` `L31` a.k.a. `&__form` add a normal `width: some px` and see if that does something